# "using static" directive doesn't cooperate with Watch window

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, c#-6.0, using-directives

I am employing the `using static` directive from [C#6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) to reference the values of an enum without providing its typename, which is great for readability. Unfortunately, when I try to add such a reference to the Watch window during debugging, it gives me a CS0103 error. Here's an example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static ConsoleApplication1.MyEnumType;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum MyEnumType
    {
        thing1,
        thing2,
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Dictionary<MyEnumType, int> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnumType, int>();

            // add the left-hand side of these expressions to watch window:
            dict[MyEnumType.thing1] = 1;  //Watch Value = 1
            dict[thing2] = 2;             //Watch Value = error CS0103: The name 'thing2' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

That final line of code compiles fine because of the using static Directive. But while debugging, if I try to add `dict[thing2]` to a Watch window I get the error. Is there any way around this?

---

**UPDATE:** This is a known bug which [has been reported](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26084), but as of today (9 months after I submitted the bug report), there has been no attempts to address it. Of course, the workaround is to simply add the type name to the watch window (which, though embarrassingly obvious, escaped me when I first posted this).

Comment: It does look like something you should report on Connect (or whatever that is now).

Comment: Done. You can vote here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/225579/using-static-directive-doesnt-cooperate-with-watch.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran your sample application through Reflector and this is the resulting Main method:

```
Dictionary<MyEnumType, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnumType, int>();
dictionary.set_Item(MyEnumType.thing1, 1);
dictionary.set_Item(MyEnumType.thing2, 2);
```

The compiler is adding `MyEnumType` to the beginning of `thing2`.  Since it appears to be a compiler feature, you aren't able to use the shortcut at runtime (in either the Watch or Immediate windows.)

Comment: That assumes the debugger (only) looks at the literal sourcecode. I don't know but it also has Reflection and PDB files to rely on.

Comment: Actually, it assumes the debugger is not using the literal sourcecode. Instead it is working off the compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I finally managed to fix it.
In my case, it was a class (class1) with static members declared on it (as "public static ...". I wasn't able to get debug information unless I specify the class when accessing the member from another class2 (i.e. class1.member). I declared my class as "static class" and now it works.